# Gravity Forms causing 403 error on home page only

Tags: php, wordpress, permissions

So I've just moved a Wordpress site to a new hosting provider, and the strangest thing is happening..

I have a contact form (the same contact form) at the bottom of each page on the site, each page loads fine, except for the home page. If I try and load the home page, I get a 403 Permission denied error. If i disabled the plugin, or remove the form from that page, it loads fine.

I suspect it might be a permissions issue but I have no idea where to even start looking. Everything else on the site works fine.

It's Gravity Forms btw.

Also, I know this might not be the right place to ask but I'm at my wits end here trying to work this out.

Answer (score 2):

So after going through some logs etc i discovered it was php mod_security that was triggering on a false positive on an iframe that gravity forms was producing. Still not sure why it was only happening on the home page though.

I contacted the hosting provider and asked them why it was happening and they just advised they'd turn it off. Which they did and it's working fine now. If anyone wants to add anything to this please do.

Comment: Same thing over here. The rule was from the COMODO ModSecurity Ruleset (which is overly aggressive sometimes), 214540: Possibly malicious iframe tag in output. Disabling also fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check your wordpress options table. Your old site link is still there, as it seems. Replace it with new one.